# Tensorflow error concerning the shape of placeholders

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm very new to TensorFlow and I try to understand the concept of Placeholders.
Let's say I have a feature set with the shape of 100x4. So I have a 100 rows of 4 different features. The target is then of a 100x1 shape. If I want to use both matrices as a training set. What I do is:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=X_train.shape)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=y_train.shape)

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4, 1]), name="weight",dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias",dtype=tf.float32)

pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y) in zip(X_train, y_train):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
            ... # some plotting and printing of results
```

Which then results into a "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (...,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(..., ...)'". More specifically, the dimensions are not equal for 'sub' in cost function.

Could someone explain how to proceed and why?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use placeholders if you want to train your data in **batches**.

**Why?**
This is done when you have a **large dataset**, for example if you want to train your classifier on an image classification problem but can't load all of your training images on your memory. What is done instead, is training your model through [batch gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent). Through this technique only a single batch of images is loaded each time and backpropagation is performed only on that batch. This requires more epochs to converge to a minima but each epoch is faster to train.

**How?**
You first define two placeholders one for the training examples `X` and one for their labels `Y`, with respective shapes `(batch_size, 4)` and `(batch_size, 1)` in your case.
Then when you want to train your model you should **feed** your data into the placeholders through a feed dictionary:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X:x_batch, Y:y_batch}) # train_op is the operation that minimizes your cost function
```

where `x_batch` and `y_batch` should be random batches from your `X_train` and `Y_train` arrays, but instead of `100` examples they should have `batch_size` examples (so that their dimensions match the placeholders' dimensions).

**Why you shouldn't do this in your case?**
Since you have a **small dataset**, that is already loaded in your memory you could use regular gradient descent.

**How?**
Just use variables (`tf.Variable()`) instead of placeholders.

```
X = tf.Variable(X_train)
Y = tf.Variable(Y_train)
```

This will create two Variable type tensors which, when initialized will take the shape and values of `X_train` and `Y_train` respectively.

Just don't forget to **initialize** them in your session:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # initialize variables
     sess.run(train_op) # no need for a feed_dict
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying reply. But I still don't understand why it wouldn't work with the placeholder, in this case the batch_size would just be equal to the first argument of X_train.shape? I added more code to contextualize the problem.

Comment: Well since the edit, I think your problem isn't with the placeholders X and Y but with the variables W and b. You need pred and Y to have the same dimensions in order to subtract them when calculating the cost function. This means that X*W+b needs to have a shape of (100,1). In order to achieve this, W needs to have a shape of (4,1). You don't need to change the variable b.

Comment: try:

W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(4,1), name="weight",dtype=tf.float64)
pred = tf.matmul(X,W) + b
# leave the rest lines unchanged
with tf.Session() as sess:
...     sess.run(init)
...     for epoch in range(training_epochs):
...         sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:X_train,Y:Y_train})

Comment: Indeed, Thank you! Replacing with matmul() and removing the zip during feeding did the trick! But why can't zip be used? Is it because the dimensions should be exactly identical?

Comment: The way you used zip, each time you were passing a single example (of the 100 you have) as the input of the model. If you wanted to do that you should make your X placeholder have a shape of (4,) and y to have a shape of (1,)

Answer (score 1):

> understand the concept of Placeholders

Placeholders are needed to hold a place for real data that you will feed in future:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=X_train.shape)
logits = nn(x)  # making some operations with x in order to calculate logits

s = tf.Session()
logits = s.run(logits, feed_dict={x: X_train})
```

because we used placeholder to make logits we need to place real data instead of placeholder in order to compute `logits`

> "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (...,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(..., ...)'"

looks like in `feed_dict={x: X_train}` your placeholder `x` has 2nd rank but `X_train` is 1st rank. Better to double-check your data.